# How map<string, set<string>> is used in this code?

Tags: c++, string, stl

This code is a slight modification of code here: [Given a string array， return all groups of strings that are anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538924/given-a-string-array-return-all-groups-of-strings-that-are-anagrams)
I have spent last 1 hour reading references of map, set and other articles but still can't understand it.

```
   #include <map>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
 int main(){
    int n; cin >>n;
    string word;
    map<string, set<string> > anagrams;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> word;
        string sortedWord(word);
        sort(sortedWord.begin(), sortedWord.end());
        anagrams[sortedWord].insert(word);
    }
    for (auto& pair : anagrams){
        for (auto& word: pair.second){
            cout << word << " ";
        }
        //cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

As I understand set is more of less an ordered vector. So when we come to this line of code

```
anagrams[sortedWord].insert(word);
```

It uses our sortedWord as a key and insert the pair into anagrams. Now as I keep on inserting pairs, anagrams is automatically sorted on the basis of sortedWord. So for example, if I insert cat, god , act in this order, anagrams will contain:

```
act act
act cat
dgo god
```

Now when I use range based loops, it prints second item of this pair. Is my understanding correct?
I have two questions. When we use sortedWord as keys, why doesn't it replace the earlier value? For eg., act cat should replace act act. Is this because of implementation of map or set? And second question, when I try to print pair.first for following input, I get some random output:

```
Input:
5
cat act dog tac god
Output(for pair.second):
act cat tac dog god
Output(for pair.first):
a c t d g o
```

Also I would be grateful if someone could give me further uses of set.

Comment: pair.first is a std::string so a range based for loop tells you each letter

Comment: @SJuan76: No order is important in `std::set`. A set with no order would be `std::unordered_set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `anagrams[sortedWord].insert(word);`
>
> It uses our sortedWord as a key and insert the pair into anagrams.

Not quite true. `anagrams` is container in which every key maps to `set`. This means, that you can have a lot of values inside of `anagrams[key]`, but they will never be duplicates.

consider input: `cat act dog god none cat`, anagrams will be more like this:

```
anagrams-+-act-+-act
         |     +-cat
         |
         +-dgo-+-dog
         |     +-god
         |
         +-enno-+-none
```

note, that there will be no duplicate of `cat`, both `dog`, and `god` input will be stored under the meaningless `dgo` key.

When you iterate over first values of pair you get keys, but since key is not `set`, but `string` you get individual characters instead of words.

In my example you would get something like `a c t d g o e n n o` which is exactly characters from keys.

Answer (score 3):

For `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string> >`, when you do this:

```
anagrams[sortedWord].insert(word);
```

It will return a reference to the `std::set<std::string>` stored at `sortedWord` or it will (essentially) create a new `set` and store it at that key. Since you are not *assigning* a `set` to it, the `set` is not replaced. But in this case, each time you have the same value for `sortedWord`, it gets added to the existing set with the `insert` method on `std::set`.

As far as the `pair.first` output, it is not random. In a map, you iterate over both the key and values (key is `first`, and value is `second`). So in this case, `pair.first` is the strings from `sortedWords`. So the first iteration is `act` and the second iteration is `dgo`. Since you then iterate over those string objects, you get the individual characters.

As far as structure, your map could be visualized as:

```
(key) -> (value - set)  
act   -> act cat tac  
dgo   -> dog god
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, so basically structure of my anagrams is as follows: act cat act tac  \newline dgo dog god

Comment: @user1425223 it seems either your formatting got messed or you miss a key once. Maybe my illustration in an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, why do the keys in the `map<string, set<string> >` not replace things?
The code does this:

```
string sortedWord(word);
sort(sortedWord.begin(), sortedWord.end());
anagrams[sortedWord].insert(word);
```

So, for any word, it is sorted first, e.g.

```
act -> act
cat -> act
```

and the sorted version is used as a key, to find the appropriate value, which is a `std::set` of strings. The unsorted version, `word` is inserted into the set. This will not replace what was there before.

Secondly, if you use a range based for loop on a string, you will get each letter.